# Rust Lifetime Book confusion

Tags: rust, lifetime

I am very confused about lifetimes, in particular an example in the rust book:
https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-03-lifetime-syntax.html

Says that:

```
fn longest(x: &str, y: &str) -> &str {
    if x.len() > y.len() {
        x
    } else {
        y
    }
}
```

Needs a lifetime specifier so the compiler knows the lifetime? Doesn't the compiler already know the lifetime? x and y are both parameters to the function, so x and y will last for the whole duration of the function so why would we need a lifetime specifier here? I don't think x and y will ever run into lifetime issues based on the code as is.

Comment: The problem is that you're *returning* the references.

Comment: This is the error stated: `help: this function's return type contains a borrowed value, but the signature does not say whether it is borrowed from x or y
help: consider introducing a named lifetime parameter`. Does this part confuse you? If not, what does?

Comment: Note: Rust, contrary to many languages, has implicit return; so `x` or `y` are actually returned. What the compiler can't figure out is how long lifetime will the returned reference be valid for.

Comment: On the same page (linked into the question), see the difference between listing 10-22 and listing 10-23.

Comment: One important point to consider is that when _calling_ this function, the compiler doesn't have access to its code. So the compiler must be able to determine the returned lifetime just from the prototype `fn longest(x: &str, y: &str) -> &str`.

Comment: @Jmb really? Because if I make a syntax error inside of the function the compiler complains? How does it know there is a syntax error if it does not have access to the code?

Comment: @caTS why do we need to know what it is borrowed from? Both x and y last the entirety of the function and both are valid. So why is it complaining?

Comment: It has access to the code when compiling _this_ function. It no longer has access to the code when compiling _other_ functions that use this one. So it must have enough information from the prototype when compiling those _other_ functions.

Comment: This example might help you undertand why it's needed: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=faa99524184d647aefad094953034ef5